# What to do with infinite long lists in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a problem, there is a list and a number, and I have to decide whether the length of the list is greater than the number. But sometimes the list is infite long. How should I solve this problem?
For example list contains the odd numbers from 10 and the number is 1000. In this case, the list is obviously longer, so the return should be true.

Comment: You do not need to visit the entire infinite list to find out it whether it is longer than 1000 elements or not

Comment: While Willem Van Onsem's suggestion is fine, for you as a beginner I would recommend you try a recursive solution without any helper functions. If you don't know how to start, it's probably advisable to read some tutorials.

Answer (score 5):

You [**`drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:drop) the first *n* elements of the list, and if the list is not empty, there is still content, we know that the list is longer. `drop n` can work with infinite lists, and [**`null :: [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:null) checks if the list is empty, the function thus looks like:

```
moreThen :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
moreThen n xs = … -- 🖘 something with drop and null
```

where I leave filling in the `…` part as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the suggestion of *leftaroundabout*, here is a recursive solution:

```
longerThan :: [a] -> Integer -> Bool
[] `longerThan` n | n < 0     = True
                  | otherwise = False
(x:xs) `longerThan` n | n <= 0     = True 
                      | otherwise  = xs `longerThan` (n-1)
```

Actually, taking the other hint, this might be a decent tutorial, so...

We have four lines and four cases (or two cases with two subcases each):

1. Empty list with a length value less than zero.  If given a negative length, empty list is longer than a negative length.  (∴ True)
2. Empty list with a non-negative length value (0, 1, 2...).  An empty list is not longer than zero or any higher number. (∴ False)
3. A non-empty list with a length value of zero or less.  Every non-empty list is longer than zero or less. (∴ True)
4. A non-empty list (x:xs) with a length, n, greater than zero.  This depends on whether or not xs is (recursively) longer than n-1.  To get the answer for (x:xs) `longerThan` n, we need to know whether xs `longerThan` n-1.

This is a good example of how functional programming differs from imperative programming.  Here we are simply defining the *logic* of the function.  We do not have to tell the "stupid computer" (Wadler) *how* to solve the recursive function.  We just tell it what the answer depends on and let it do the work.

Going from case 4, the computer will proceed until one of the other (*two*) cases apply.  Applying the recursion repeated some number of times either: a) the list will become empty (with a positive length value) -> case 2 (∴ False), or b) the length value will become zero and applied to a non-empty list -> case 3 (∴ True).

If you are coming from an imperative programming background, it may take a while to unlearn the need to tell the computer how to proceed step-by-step.  The functional programming paradigm is about writing a logical specification that the computer can solve on its own (so to speak).

I hope this makes sense.